# Predict LR with svyglm and svrepdesign

Tags: r, logistic-regression, predict, survey

I'm trying to fit a logistic regression model on my survey data.

How do i predict the logistic regression model using `svyglm`?

Survey designs:

```
dhs.svy <- svydesign(id =~ HV001+couple, strata =~ HV023, 
                     weights =~ V005, fpc =~ fpc1+fpc2, data = dhs)
dhs.svy.rep <- as.svrepdesign(dhs.svy)
```

Models:

```
model1 <- svyglm(score ~ man.edu + woman.edu, design = dhs.svy, family = binomial)
model2 <- svyglm(score ~ man.edu + woman.edu, design = dhs.svy.rep, family = binomial)

predict(model1, type = "response")  #works
predict(model2, type = "response")  #does not work
```

Using a `model2` with a `svrepdesign` object (instead of a `svydesign` object) in the `predict` function gives an error:

> "Error in print.svrepstat(x): incorrect structure of svrepstat object."
>   Using a `model1` with a `svydesign` object in `predict` works fine.

Is there a way to make an `svrepdesign` object work in `predict`?
And how do i specify which dataset to use in the `predict` function?

Answer (score 0):

i think this is a bug in the survey library.  i've submitted a bug report to the maintainer.  here's the workaround.  thanks!

```
library(survey)
data(scd)

# use BRR replicate weights from Levy and Lemeshow
repweights<-2*cbind(c(1,0,1,0,1,0), c(1,0,0,1,0,1), c(0,1,1,0,0,1),
c(0,1,0,1,1,0))
scdrep<-svrepdesign(data=scd, type="BRR", repweights=repweights, combined.weights=FALSE)

# simple svrepglm object
rep.glm <- svyglm( arrests ~ alive , scdrep )

# breaks at the `print.svrepstat` call
predict( rep.glm , newdata = data.frame( alive = 1:3 ) )

# put it into an object rather than printing it to the screen..
w <- predict( rep.glm , newdata = data.frame( alive = 1:3 ) )

# override the default to get what you expect
survey:::print.svystat(w)
```